# Частичное выравнивание Header в MenuItem (или Menu) | WPF

Tags: wpf

[image]

Здравствуйте. Извините за, скорее всего, глупый вопрос.
Как выровнять текст в меню так, чтобы было что-то вроде этого: (красное на место синего)

```
**Menu**
---------------------------
| New file       [Ctrl+N] |
| Exit           [Ctrl+Q] |
---------------------------
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Menu VerticalAlignment="top">
     <MenuItem Header="Menu">
         <MenuItem Header="New file"></MenuItem>
         <Separator />
         <MenuItem Header="Exit [Ctrl+Q]" Command="local:MainWindow.exitApp"></MenuItem>
     </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</Grid>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Menu VerticalAlignment="top">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu">
            <MenuItem Header="New file"></MenuItem>
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Q"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

NB! InputGestureText - не задает горячую клавишу, оно только задает отображаемый текст